# libav logs to a file

Tags: logging, libav

I want to redirect libav log messages to a file. FFmpeg have a environment variable "FFREPORT" to specify the file path to dump log messages. Is there any variable in LIBAV to specify log file path.?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to register your logger using av_log_set_callback probably.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to set:

av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_VERBOSE);

then all prints of LibAV are sent to stderr. In order to redirect stderr to a file you can use '2>' :

*myprogram     2> log.txt*

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to redirect lib-av logs to a particular file in my code. So I did a workaround and redirected logs to a file. it working now.